# why are variables not showing up as members of objects?

Tags: javascript, class, object

hey guys i'm working on some code for a class project and for some reason the demo code i got in class is not working the same way. the errors aren't making any since can i get some help debugging i know its probably retarded. thanks a lot in advance.

```
function BuildGrid()
{
//begin with a BeginVertical() call so that controls
//are stacked vertically
GUILayout.BeginVertical();
GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

//begin loopping for the rows
for(var i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    //call BeginHorizontal() so that controls are stacked
    //horizontally
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

    //begin looping for the columns
    for(var j=0; j<cols; j++)
    {
        //getting the card object that resides 
        //at this location in the array
        var card:Object = aGrid[i][j];

        //the definition for the backside (visible part for the card
        var img : String;

        //check if the card is face up, if so, show the robot part
        //if not show the wrench
        if(card.ifFaceUp)
        {
            img = card.img;
        }
        else
        {
            img = "wrench";

        }

        //create a button using a picture instead of
        //text.  Getting the picture from the Resources
        if(GUILayout.Button(Resources.Load(img),
            GUILayout.Width(cardW)))
            {
                flipCardFaceUp(card);
                //print to the debug the name of the picture
                Debug.Log(card.img);
            }
    }
    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}
GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
GUILayout.EndVertical();
}//end buildGrid
```

Class where ifFaceUP and img are defined

```
class Card extends System.Object
{
//is the card face up
var ifFaceUp:boolean = false;

//has the card been matched
var ifMatched:boolean = false;

//image for the card
var img: String;

//constructor
function Card(img : String)
{
    this.img = img;

}
}
```

errors:    http://puu.sh/2clHw

Comment: var card:Object = aGrid[i][j]; What type of objects does the aGrid contain? Later you try: card.ifFaceUp but ifFaceUp is not a member of Object so that would not work would it? You should maybe convert card to the right type: var card:Card = aGrid[i][j];

Comment: Maybe add C# tag as well, looks like the code you posted is C#

Comment: aGrid[i][j]  is a 2d array of objects.

Comment: JavaScript is not strongly typed but .net is. So even if the instance card is of type Card you still have to declare it as Card and not object. var card:Card = (Card) somevariable I think is how you do it in C#. Look for type conversion in .net.

Comment: I think everything extends System.Object so you might as well leave that out.

Comment: HMR its not C# JavaScript and C# are close in some aspects but it is mainly a web based language. I'm currently using JavaScript because it works better in unity because the games you create in unity are web based.

Comment: The code you posted is not JavaScript. JavaScript is prototype based and not class based so you can't declare a class. It's also not strongly typed so you can't declare a variable as a certain type. var card:Card doesn't work in JavaScript nor does Class card ... You may be using JS in .net but that's not the same as ECMA JavaScript

Comment: ok if i wrote it in C# my For loop would be int = 0 not var = 0 the reason being in javascript does not support int = 0 it must be declared as a var. i do beleave i am looking at the file it and the demo code is in and they are both .js files dont treat me like an idiot because i know the language im writing in

Comment: Ok, if you say so. I'm not trying to upset you. It might be called JavaScript but it isn't ECMA JS for sure.

Comment: is there a way i can email it to you so you can see it all. including the demo code that works fine.

Comment: The Unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the script you emailed I can see that aGrid contains Objects of type Card. In ECMA JavaScript nothing is strongly typed. ECMA is the JS that runs in the browser. Your JS is .net code that runs on the server when the browser requests a certain page or used as a desktop application (not sure what type of app it is). Even though it's called JavaScript it only means that the syntax looks like JavaScript but since it's .net code it's completely different from JavaScript (ECMA).

One thing you can do with ECMA JS is:

```
var notStronglyTyped=22; // is int
notStronglyTyped = "hello";// changed to string
notStronglyTyped.subString();// can call subString now because it's a method of string
```

This will not work in .net since .net is strongly typed (and class based but that's not the problem at hand). Hence the int when you declare a variable:

```
var i:int=0;// the :int gives a syntax error in ECMA JS since it doesn't exist.
```

Strongly typed means that the variable needs to be declared or converted to a certain type before you execute functions or access properties that are accociated with that type. substring is a method of String but I can't call it on an int:

```
var i:int=0;
i.subString();//won't work in .net unless you cast it to another type.

((String)i).subString();//might work but I don't know the exact syntax for .net JS.
```

In short; when retrieving cards from aGrid I would suggest declaring them as Card since you don't need to type cast later when you declare it as Object. The array aGrid contains objects of type Card anyway so you should not get a warning or error there:

```
    card = new Card("robot" + (i+1) + "Missing" + theMissingPart);
    //instance card is of type Card
    aCards.Add(card);//aCards contains items of type Card
                ....
    aGrid[i][j] = aCards[somNum];
//aGrid is filled with items from aCards which in turn contains items of type Card
```

At some point in your code you do:

```
    var card:Object = aGrid[i][j];
```

I am not sure why since aGrid contains Card type (everything is type Object because everything inherits from Object). So why not declare the variable card as an instance of Card?

```
    var card:Card = aGrid[i][j];
```

That should solve your problem right there. I can't run the code here because I have not set up a .net develop environment but I'm sure that solves it.

You can look up articles on google on type casting ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typecasting)) you can imagine the headaches that come with it when you fill an array or list with mixed types. This is where [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) can lend a helping hand but it might be too early to get into that as it can make your head explode :-)

Comment: Please not that card:Object occurs 4 times in the 2 files you posted.